# How to run telethon accounts in parallel to each other?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, telethon

I’m using Thread, but I can’t launch several accounts at once, what should I do? I will attach the code that launches the accounts below. Me need for all accounts use method send_message.

```
tdesk = TDesktop(tdata)
client = await tdesk.ToTelethon(session=f"{tdata + '/tdata'}.session", flag=UseCurrentSession)

usernames_split = np.array_split(usernames, len(accounts))
usernames_split = [arr.tolist() for arr in usernames_split]
       
    ready_usernames = {}
    for account in accounts:
        for usernames in usernames_split:
            ready_usernames.setdefault(account, usernames)

    for key, item in ready_usernames.items():
        Thread(target=main, args=(group_name, key, item, message)).start()

def main(group_name: str, account: str, usernames: list, message: str):
    asyncio.run(telegram_thread(group_name=group_name, account=account, usernames=usernames, message=message))
```

I tried using asyncio with tasks and multiprocessing, with multiprocessing I get an error, but asyncio runs one account